# How to recover from DDOS'ed internet

Tags: king-of-the-hill

The internet has failed.  DDoS attacks are now rampant and widespread.  It is up to you to take control and repair the internet.

Each bot will control 20 nodes in this network.  Every node is either *active* or *safe*, has an owner, and has a strength, which starts at 2. Every active node is connected to all other active nodes.

Each turn, you will receive a list of all active nodes with their strength.  For each of the active nodes that you own, you either:

1. Designate an *active* node you want to transfer your *entire* strength to, or
2. Save and increase its strength

Then the following happens *in order*:

1. A Node choosing to save its strength will increase its strength by 1.
2. All nodes choosing to transfer their strength will simultaneously transfer their entire strength to the new node.
3. If a node was transferred strength from an enemy node, an attack will ensue.  If an enemy *owner* collectively transfers more strength than the original owner (and all other attackers), then that enemy becomes the new owner.  The strength of that node then becomes the strength of the attacker.  If there is a tie for strength, then the owner will be chosen randomly.
4. All nodes left without any strength will be considered *safe*, and gives 1 point to the owner.

After 100 games of 100 turns, the owner with the most safe nodes across all games wins. **EDIT: I changed it from 2000 to 100 turns, as it ended up that the last 1900 turns were useless**

## IO

You will be passed the list of active nodes (via command line args) like the following:

```
F20 F4 E7 E2 E20 F2
```

`F` designates that the node is a friendly node, and `E` designates that the node is an enemy.

For each of your friendly nodes, you should return an action (via STDOUT) like the following:

```
0,0 1,3 5,0
```

The above would mean that you want to increase your strength of the first node, use your second node to attack the fourth node, and your last node will transfer its strength the first node (and if nobody attacks it, it will become a safe node).

After returning, your program should quit.

## Scoreboard

> accumulator got 3240 points
>
> classy got 2370 points
>
> dumbot got 2262 points
>
> random_bot got 1603 points
>
> smarter_random_bot got 1319 points
>
> steady_bot got 1097 points

The controller can be found here: https://github.com/nathanmerrill/NetAttack

Comment: The controller contradicts with the specification: "If an enemy owner collectively transfers **more** strength than the original owner...". Currently it's **equal or more**.

Comment: @randomra: in the spec it says: *If there is a tie for strength, then the owner will be chosen randomly*

Comment: @NathanMerrill I assumed if the attackers tie.

Comment: The last remaining node is stuck waiting until the end of the game, right? There's no way for him to run away?

Comment: @acbabis correct, but I actually test for that and end the game prematurely at that point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Accumulator, Python

Let's get this party started! My submission should work both on Python 2 and Python 3.

```
import sys

inputs = [(i, x[0], int(x[1:])) for (i, x) in enumerate(sys.argv[1].split())]

own_nodes = sorted([(s,i) for (i,o,s) in inputs if o == 'F'])
targets = sorted([(s,i) for (i,o,s) in inputs if o == 'E'])

if targets:
    t_copy = targets[:]
    out = ""
    total_str = 0
    attackers = []
    for (s,i) in own_nodes:
        attackers += [i]
        if t_copy:
            total_str += s
            if t_copy[0][0] < total_str - 1:
                j = max([j for j in range(len(t_copy)) if t_copy[j][0] < total_str - 1])
                out += " ".join([str(k) + "," + str(t_copy[j][1]) for k in attackers]) + " "
                attackers = []
                total_str = 0
                t_copy = t_copy[:j] + t_copy[j+1:]
    if attackers:
        if t_copy:
            out += " ".join([str(k) + "," + str(t_copy[0][1]) for k in attackers])
        else:
            out += " ".join([str(k) + "," + str(attackers[0]) for k in attackers])
else:
    out = " ".join([str(i) + "," + str(own_nodes[0][1]) for (s,i) in own_nodes])

print(out.rstrip())
sys.stdout.flush()
```

The idea is really simple.
I start enumerating my nodes in ascending order of strength, keeping a running sum of the strengths.
When the sum exceeds the strength of the weakest enemy node (+1 for a possible increase), I attack that node and remove it from the pool, reset the sum, and continue.
At the end, if the strongest nodes can't find anyone to attack, they'll collect more strength.

*EDIT:* Accumulator is now a bit smarter.
Instead of always attacking the weakest enemy node, it accumulates the strength until it could do so, and then attacks the strongest free node it can with that strength.
Also, if there are still enemies left at the end, any unassigned nodes will attack the weakest remaining enemy, just in case it decides to transfer its strength away.

Answer (score 4):

## Classy, Python3

```python
import random, sys
f,e,p=[],[],[]
for si,s in enumerate(sys.argv[1].split()):
    if s[0]=='F': f+=[(int(s[1:]),si)]
    else: e+=[(int(s[1:]),si)]
f=sorted(f,key=lambda t:t[0]);r=4
f1,f2,f3=f[:len(f)//r],f[len(f)//r:len(f)//r*2],f[len(f)//r*2:]
for fa in f3:
    ea=[t for t in e if t[0]<fa[0]]
    p+=[(fa[1],random.choice(ea)[1])] if ea else [(fa[1],fa[1])]
for fd,fs in zip(f1,reversed(f2)):
    p+=[(fs[1],fd[1])]
    p+=[(fd[1],fd[1])]
if len(e)==0: p=[(fe[1],0) for fe in f]
for t in p: print(t[0],',',t[1],' ',sep='',end='')
sys.stdout.flush()
```

The bot splits its own nodes into 3 categories based on strength and each node acts according to its category.

- Each strong node attacks a random enemy node which it can beat.
- Each middle node supports it's weak node pair.
- Each weak node supports itself.

Result against Accumulator and the two sample bots:

```
smarter_random_bot got 1301 points
random_bot got 1841 points
Accumulator got 2178 points
Classy got 2580 points
```

Answer (score 2):

## Dumbot, Nodejs

```js
var input = process.argv.splice(2);
var regexp = new RegExp(" ", "gm");
input = String(input).split(regexp);
var nodes = [];
var targets = [];
for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
    if(input[i].charAt(0) == "F")
        nodes.push(i);
    else
        targets.push(i);
}
var result = "";
var length = nodes.length;
for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){
    if(targets.length>0)
        result += nodes.shift() + "," + targets.shift() + " ";
    else
        result += nodes.shift() + ",0 ";
}
console.log(result);
```

The bot will attack without any thinking or strategy. The main goal is to ensure a lot of safe node right at the beginning. Be aware that this bot make an infinite loop with accumulator.

Answer (score 2):

## SteadyBot, Node.js

```js
(new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var input = process.argv[2];
    if(input) {
        resolve(input);
    } else {
        process.stdin.once('data', function(data){
            resolve(data.toString());
        });
    }
})).then(function(input) {
    return input.trim().split(' ');
}).then(function(nodes) {
    var friends = [], enemies = [];
    nodes.forEach(function(value, index) {
        var data = { index: index, strength: parseInt(value.substring(1)) };
        if(value[0] === 'F') {
            friends.push(data);
        } else {
            enemies.push(data);
        }
    });

    function weaknessCompare(a, b) {
        return (a.strength > b.strength) ? -1 : ((a.strength < b.strength) ? 1 : 0);
    }

    friends.sort(weaknessCompare);
    enemies.sort(weaknessCompare);

    if(enemies.length === 0) {
        friends.forEach(function(friend) {
            friend.target = 0;
        });
    } else {
        if(friends.length > 0) {
            var strongest = friends[0];
            for(var i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {
                var enemy = enemies[i];
                if(enemy.strength + 1 < strongest.strength) {
                    strongest.target = enemy.index;
                    break;
                }
            };
        }
        if(friends.length > 1) {
            friends[1].target = friends[friends.length - 1].index;
        }
    }

    console.log(friends.map(function(friend) {
        return friend.index + ',' +
                (typeof friend.target === 'number' ? friend.target : friend.index);
    }).join(' '));
});
```

- Assumes enemies won't reinforce large nodes: Largest friendly node attacks strongest enemy it can beat under this assumption.
- Assumes that weakest target will be attacked: Second largest friendly node moves to weakest friendly node each round.
- Wants lots of free strength: Other nodes wait.

Comment: I'm unsure why, but this bot isn't returning properly (it prints an empty string).   The other nodejs bot works, so I'd recommend taking a look at it.  I should also mention that I just installed nodejs, and while I know javascript, I may be missing something specific to nodejs.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. When I do `node SteadyBot.js F20 F4 E7 E2 E20 F2`, it works for me. Could you please tell me the input for which it is failing?

Comment: @NathanMerrill I rewrote it to also work with stdin. Hope that fixes it. `cat  F20 F4 E7 E2 E20 F2 | node SteadyBot.js`

Comment: @acbabis Input is given as one big argument.

Comment: @acbabis randomra is correct.  You are going to get 1 big argument, the list (unless, you get the call as well like C++, in which case, you will get 2).

Comment: @NathanMerrill I fixed the problem and successfully ran it with your controller after adding a `node steadyBot.js` command.txt file. Thanks for your help.